# What is the default ARIA role for an SVG?

Tags: html, svg, accessibility, wai-aria

I have been trying to determine what the default role of an SVG tag should be if the `role` attribute is not present and the document contains visible graphics.

Using Chrome's accessibility tools it tells me that the role is `SVGRoot`:

[image]

However this is not a valid ARIA role, it's one of Chrome's own roles it uses internally.

I have been able to find a lot more information through this document: [WAI-ARIA Graphics Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/graphics-aria-1.0/), it indicates which roles are allowed to be used on an SVG tag, but I can't seem to narrow down which should be the default role.

What role should user agents assume SVGs to be by default if there is no valid `role` attribute provided?

Comment: I don't think there is a default, since SVG is for graphics/diagrams, there are already roles which suffice `graphic`, `diagram`,`chart`, etc, coupled w/ title/desc, you should be covered.

Comment: @Napoli, so how do screen readers decide how they are going to deal with them or any other element that doesn't have a default role? Do they normally decide to map it to a default role anyway?

Comment: @Godwin, No.  If an html element does not have a role, or you set the role to 'presentation', then the screen reader does not know the purpose of that element.  No default role will be mapped to it.  Creating an accessible SVG is a huge research area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the ARIA in HTML document, [SVG has no default corresponding role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#svg)

"No corresponding role" status is defined as following:

> The elements marked with *No corresponding role*, in the second column of the table do not have any implicit ARIA semantics, but they do have meaning and this meaning may be represented in roles, states and properties not provided by ARIA, and exposed to users of assistive technology via accessibility APIs. It is therefore recommended that web developers add a role attribute to a semantically neutral element such as a div or span, rather than overriding the semantics of the listed elements.

As already answerd by @josh, allowed roles for SVG elements are `application`, `document`, or `img`

Comment: Awesome. For our use case I'm going not going to assume a role but look at SVGs with no role as a indicator on its own. I think that aligns best with what the W3C and WCAG has dictated.

Comment: According to the linked document (which in turn links to the SVG-AAM), SVGs now have an implicit `graphics-document` role. https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/#details-id-66

Comment: @ericgio - While you are correct that the spec says that SVG *should* map to `graphics-document` by default, this is a relatively recent change to the SVG-AAM spec. Most browsers do not actually follow the spec in this regard. Frankly, the spec does not make this default mapping very clear. I think the mapping also depends partly on whether the SVG has an accessible name such as a `<title>`. At time of writing I would advise that it is safest not to rely on default semantic mapping for any SVG elements. Add the role you intend, explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

SVGs have no implicit aria roles on their own, however developers can (and probably should) assign one of the following roles: `application`, `document`, or `img`.

Use `application` if your SVG has focusable elements requiring user input.

Use `document` if your SVG contains mostly informational text that is not interactive.

Use `img` if your SVG is purely visual or uses a collection of elements to make up a single image.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance